# How do I mount an IMG file in Ubuntu for Photorec (beginner at linux)

Tags: mount, photorec

I created a copy of my 1tb HDD drive from ddrescue and wanted to mount this IMG file to then recover data from Photorec.

How to mount an IMG file as if it was an actual HDD/pen drive inserted by USB. Please explain in detail as I'm getting the hang of ubuntu systems; used to use Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Photorec doesn't run on mounted filesystems, you should run it on the image itself:

```
sudo photorec /path/to/disk.img
```

Comment: Will this work with an encrypted drive, will this process recover all data?

Comment: @Ashton with an encrypted drive, if the encryption is worth anything at all, no data is likely to be recovered. That's pretty much the point of encryption

Comment: The thing is I'm using try ubuntu, and when I try to decrypt the drive it doesn't decrypt even when the password is correct

Comment: @Ashton what did you use for encryption?

Comment: It was the encryption when installing ubuntu

Comment: @Ashton did you save the recovery passphrase shown on first login after encryption? If not, there's nothing to be done.

Comment: Late update, but I was somehow able to recover a lot of personal data that was lost even through the encryption. The only problem is it obviously recovered each and every file, which was the point I gave up, knowing I still have the recovered data but can't be asked to sort it. :) Thanks for helping me <3